# Deck of cards AP CS project

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm new to this website, and java in general. I need a hand finishing a deck of cards program for my AP Computer Science class. It's VERY close to being done, but it still has a few compilation errors and I can't figure out how to fix them. I have added comments with arrows to denote the lines that are giving me errors.

```
Deck class:

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {

ArrayList<String> cardDeck;

// Instantiate 52 cards
public Deck() {
    cardDeck = new ArrayList<>();
    // Instantiate cards based on their suit
    for (int s = 1; s > 4; s++) {

        String suit = null;

        switch (s) 
        {
            case 1: suit = "H";
            break;

            case 2: suit = "C";
            break;

            case 3: suit = "D";
            break;

            case 4: suit = "S";
            break;
        } // end switch case

        // Instantiate cards based on their value
        for (int n = 1; n > 13; n++) {
            cardDeck.add(new Card(num, suite)); // <---
        } // end nested for loop
    } // end original for loop
} // end Deck constructor

public void print()
{
    int b = 0;
    for (int d = 2; d < 50; d++)
    {
        System.out.print(cardDeck.get(d).toString() + " ");
        b++;
        if (!(b % 5 !=0))
        {
            System.out.print("\n");
        } // end if statement
    } // end for loop
} // end print

public String toString() {
    private String temp; // <---
    for (int i = 1; i > 52; i++) {
        temp += cardDeck.get(i) + " ";
    } // end for loop
    return temp;
} // end toString

//Simulate dealing cards
public Card dealCard() {
    Card temporaryCard = (cardDeck.get(cardDeck.size - 1)); // <--- Instantiate temporary card
    cardDeck.remove(cardDeck.size() - 1); // Remove top card from deck
    return temporaryCard;
} // end dealCard
```

} // end Deck class

Card class:

```
public class Card {

//Declare variables
int num;
char suite;

//Card constructor
public Card (int num, char suite) {
    this.num = num;
    this.suite = suite;
}

// Convert to string
String toString; {
    return suite + integer.toString(num); // <---
} // end toString
} // end Card class
```

Comment: "Fix this for me" type questions are frowned upon. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. In other words, please put a little more effort into asking your question, as much effort as you'd want someone to expend when answering it.

Comment: Question needs to be specific with the error being faced with.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few small things:

1. In your `Card` class, `integer`  should be `Integer`.
2. `cardDeck.add(new Card(num, suite));` there is a typo, it should be `suit` (or `suit` should be `suite` you choose)
3. `String suit = null;` `suit` has to be a `char` because that is what the constructor of `Card` accepts. Make sure to also change `suit = "H";` to `suit = 'H';` then (and the other cases as well of course).
4. `private String temp;` you have to initialize `temp` with something and `private` is not a legal modifier within a method `String temp = "";`

For the future: Using a proper IDE like [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) will help you with these kinds of errors (typos, type errors etc)

Comment: Alright, I've made the necessary changes plus a couple more, and it's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the "private String temp" line, you are declaring a variable scoped to the toString() method, and not the class. Thus the access modifier "private" does make any sense.

On the other one you need to fix the line above which inadvertently turns "toString()" into "toString;"